# Custom offseh condition on Logstash for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, logstash, devops, etl

I use jdbc interface on Logstash to upload a part of data from Postgres to ElasticSearch. Is it possible to configure Logstash to use WHERE instead of OFFSET?

My config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log"
    type => "logstash-logs"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }

  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/external_jars/postgresql-42.5.4.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.1:5432/tyver_stage"
    jdbc_user => "tyver_stage"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    schedule => "*/5 * * * *"
    statement => "
      SELECT
        c.*,
        COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) AS order_column,
        CASE
          WHEN ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id) = ARRAY[null]::integer[] THEN ARRAY[]::integer[]
          ELSE ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id)
        END AS viewed_by
      FROM
        creatives as c
          LEFT JOIN
        user_creative_views ucv ON ucv.creative_id = c.id
      WHERE
        (c.updated_at >= :sql_last_value OR (c.updated_at IS NULL AND c.created_at >= :sql_last_value))
      GROUP BY
        c.id
      ORDER BY
        COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) ASC
    "
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "order_column"
    tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_page_size => 10000
    record_last_run => true
    clean_run => false
  }
}

filter {

}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["172.17.0.1:9200"]
    index => "tyver_index_creatives"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

And as the result i have following SQL queries:

```sql
 SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
        c.*,
        COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) AS order_column,
        CASE
          WHEN ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id) = ARRAY[null]::integer[] THEN ARRAY[]::integer[]
          ELSE ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id)
        END AS viewed_by
      FROM
        creatives as c
          LEFT JOIN
        user_creative_views ucv ON ucv.creative_id = c.id
      WHERE
        (c.updated_at >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000' OR (c.updated_at IS NULL AND c.created_at >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000+0000'))
      GROUP BY
        c.id
      ORDER BY
        COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) ASC
    ) AS "t1" LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 20000
```

It's very expensive by resources because query `LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 20000` is equal to `LIMIT 30000`. Here I have 35M+ rows and 100Gb+ of data and it's too heavy to upload it using this way. Is it possible to configure Logstash to use WHERE instead of OFFSET like `WHERE COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) > :the_last_order_value`?

Comment: You can adjust your query to use a WHERE clause that compares against the last known value of the order_column. Unfortunately, the jdbc_paging_enabled option in Logstash's JDBC input plugin relies on LIMIT and OFFSET for pagination, which isn't the most efficient for very large datasets due to the way OFFSET skips over rows.
Another approach is to avoid OFFSET is to manage pagination in your application logic by maintaining the last processed order_column value and using it in the WHERE clause for subsequent queries.

Comment: @TSCAmerica.com I'm afraid I didn't quite understand you. If you post an example of how to add pagination with WHERE statement and without jdbc_paging_enabled option, I'll mark it as the correct answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQl query

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) AS order_column,
    CASE
        WHEN ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id) = ARRAY[null]::integer[] THEN ARRAY[]::integer[]
        ELSE ARRAY_AGG(ucv.user_id)
    END AS viewed_by
FROM
    creatives AS c
LEFT JOIN
    user_creative_views ucv ON ucv.creative_id = c.id
WHERE
    COALESCE(c.updated_at, c.created_at) > :sql_last_value
GROUP BY
    c.id
```